# Limit users to create only one profile with Devise in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a user model and profile model using devise.

user has_one profile
profile belongs_to user

How can I throw an error if a user that already has a profile associate to them when they try to create another profile.

so if a user goes to example.com/profiles/new it would throw the error

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this. I suggest you look up the Rails documentation for ActiveRecord validations and/or hooks (e.g. before_create)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could do something like that:

**profiles_controller.rb**

```
def new
  if current_user.profile.empty?
    # create profil for user
  else
    # raise error which doesn't make sense or redirect like
    redirect_to user_profile_path
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Still learning things like this, but it really helps!

Answer (score 1):

@auL5agoi answer doesn't prevent someone from accessing the create action though.  You want to run the check on both actions.

```
def ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :check_profile_presence, only: [:new, :create]

  def new
  end

  def create
  end

  private

  def check_profile_presence
    redirect_to user_profile_path if current_user.profile.exists?
  end
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to change your model! This will prevent problems in your db ... add to your `model/profile.rb`.

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord 
    belongs_to :user
    validates_uniqueness_of :user_id

    #[... other codes...]
end
```